# Python 2.7 i have problems with the date format

Tags: python-2.7

I have a problem at the end of my query with the dates

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

##chart excel advanced
import mysql.connector
import arrow
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
##/home/andrews/Downloads/GRAILS/tarjetasadicionales/web-app/tempFiles/
workbook = Workbook('output2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
##ADD A CHART SHEET
chartsheet = workbook.add_chartsheet()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
         user='root',
         password='root',
         host='127.0.0.1',
         database='adicionales')


cur = conn.cursor()

##hire_start = arrow.get('2017-06-14 00:00:00')
##hire_start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ')
##hire_end = arrow.get('2017-06-14 23:59:59')
##hire_end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ')

query = ("""select
concat(substr(c.fecha_gestion, 9, 2),'/',substr(c.fecha_gestion, 6, 
2),'/',substr(c.fecha_gestion, 1, 4)) as 'Fecha Gestión'
, case substr(c.fecha_gestion, 6, 2)
when '01' then 'ENERO'
when '02' then 'FEBRERO'
when '03' then 'MARZO'
when '04' then 'ABRIL'
when '05' then 'MAYO'
when '06' then 'JUNIO'
when '07' then 'JULIO'
when '08' then 'AGOSTO'
when '09' then 'SEPTIEMBRE'
when '10' then 'OCTUBRE'
when '11' then 'NOVIEMBRE'
when '12' then 'DICIEMBRE'
else 'NO APLICA'
end as 'Mes Gestión'
, substr(c.fecha_gestion, 1, 4) as 'Año Gestión'
, concat(substr(c.fecha_gestion, 9, 2),'/',substr(c.fecha_gestion, 6, 
2),'/',substr(c.fecha_gestion, 1, 4)) as 'Fecha Consolidado'
, 'PLUS WIRELESS' as 'Nombre call center'
, upper(c.nombre_vendedor) as 'Usuario'
, 'CEDULA' as 'Tipo_Id'
, a.cedula as 'Id_adicional'
, upper(a.nacionalidad) as 'Nacionalidad'
, upper(a.primer_apellido) as 'Primer_apellido'
, upper(a.segundo_apellido) as 'Segundo_apellido'
, upper(a.primer_nombre) as 'Primer_nombre'
, upper(a.segundo_nombre) as 'Segundo_nombre'
, upper(a.nombre_tarjeta) as 'Nombre_tarjeta'
, a.fecha_nacimiento as 'Fecha_nacimiento'
, upper(a.sexo) as 'Sexo'
, upper(a.estado_civil) as 'Estado_civil'
, upper(a.parentesco) as 'Parentesco'
, upper(a.observaciones) as 'Observaciones'
, a.cupo_otorgado as 'Cupo'
, c.cuenta as 'Cuenta_titular'
, c.identificacion as 'Id_titular'
, upper(c.producto) as 'Producto'
, upper(concat(c.apellidos,' ',c.nombres)) as 'Nombre_completo_titular'
, upper(c.provincia_trab) as 'Provincia_trabajo'
, upper(c.ciudad_trab) as 'Ciudad_trabajo'
, upper(c.calle_principal_trab) as 'Avenida/Calle principal_trabajo'
, upper(c.numeracion_trab) as 'Numeración_trabajo'
, upper(c.calle_transversal_trab) as 'Calle_transversal_trabajo'
, upper(c.sector_trab) as 'Sector/Barrio_trabajo'
, upper(c.tipo_trab) as 'Casa_departamento_trabajo'
, upper(c.referencia_trab) as 'Referencia_trabajo'
, upper(concat(calle_principal_trab, ' ', numeracion_trab, ' ', 
calle_transversal_trab, ' ', sector_trab, ' ', referencia_trab)) as 
'Información_concatenada_trabajo'
, c.caracteres_trab as 'Caracteres_trabajo'
, upper(c.provincia_domic) as 'Provincia_domicilio'
, upper(c.ciudad_domic) as 'Ciudad_domicilio'
, upper(c.calle_principal_domic) as 'Avenida/Calle principal_domicilio'
, upper(c.numeracion_domic) as 'Numeración_domicilio'
, upper(c.calle_transversal_domic) as 'Calle_transversal_domicilio'
, upper(c.sector_domic) as 'Sector/Barrio_domicilio'
, upper(c.tipo_vivienda) as 'Casa_departamento_domicilio'
, upper(c.referencia_domic) as 'Referencia_domicilio'
, upper(concat(calle_principal_domic, ' ', numeracion_domic, ' ', 
calle_transversal_domic, ' ', sector_domic, ' ', referencia_domic)) as 
'Información_concatenada_trabajo'
, c.caracteres_dom as 'Caracteres_domicilio'
, upper(c.entrega) as 'Trabajo/Domicilio'
, upper(c.nombre_contacto) as 'Persona de contacto'
, upper(c.rango_visita) as 'Rango de visita'
, c.celular_contacto as 'Celular'
, c.telefono_trab_contacto as 'Telefono_trabajo'
, c.telefono_dom_contacto as 'Telefono_casa'
, c.estado_cta_digital as 'EmisionEstadoCtaDigital'
from clientes c, adicional a
where c.subestado_gestion_id in (select id from subestado where type = 
'Exitoso')
and c.id = a.clientes_id
and c.fecha_gestion between '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 
23:59:59'
""")
```

here i have the problem with the date format '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 23:59:59' 
removing this line of code the query works and i can see the excel file and c.fecha_gestion between '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 23:59:59'

```
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
print(results)

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chartsheet.set_chart(chart)

for i, row in enumerate(results):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
       worksheet.write(i, j, row[j])

# Insert the chart into the worksheet IN D1.
worksheet.insert_chart('Z1', chart)
##SHEET NUM AND THE VALUES TO COUNT FORM        
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$59649'})
workbook.close()
```

This is the link of the database

[THIS IS THE LINK OF THE DATABASE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxTOBXhCgP8-WklSMW1pdzZhazQ)

Comment: Do you get an exception when you include the date range as part of your `where` clause?

Comment: i don't get any errors but at the i just dont get the data, but when i comment this  code and c.fecha_gestion between '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 
23:59:59'
from the query i will get all results but i need is to insert the data in this format 2017-05-04 00:00:00

Comment: That is puzzling because the syntax looks correct. You might try adding `conn.raise_on_warnings = True` before executing the query. By default it won't throw exceptions, so that might provide some information about why it's having trouble with `between '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 23:59:59'`.

Comment: it doesn't show any errors the thing is that i dont get any data,  but when i remove this line **"and c.fecha_gestion between '2017-05-04 00:00:00' and '2017-05-08 "**,  i get all the data, but i need the data only from does dates, its weird because  its valid code????

Comment: I have uploaded the database so you can check it out ..

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following query:

```
SELECT c.fecha_gestion FROM clientes c where c.id in (select a.clientes_id from adicional a) order by c.fecha_gestion asc
```

The date range for `c.fecha_gestion` was `2017-05-12 16:37:18` to `2017-06-13 09:49:00`.

These are all greater than the maximum date of `2017-05-08 23:59:59` specified in your `between` statement.

The `c.id = a.clientes_id` seems to be restricting records in `clientes` for the date range you are querying.

**EDIT**

Here are the results running your query against the data dump, without the `between` clause, adding column `c.fecha_gestion` to the selected columns, and with `order by c.fecha_gestion asc`.

Look the minimum date value for `c.fecha_gestion`, `2017-05-12 16:37:18`. So for this query, there are no rows with `c.fecha_gestion` having a value between `2017-05-04 00:00:00` and `2017-05-08 23:59:59`, and that's why you get no results with the `between` condition:

[image: query and result grid]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, but my posted query above is valid MYSQL but i don't know why it isn't working with PYTHON, i also added the database so someone please can help me !!!!

Comment: Could you include the table `subestado` too? I got an error executing the query after loading the database because that table seemed to be missing, so I had to take that part out.

Comment: Hi and thanks this is the other databases.https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxTOBXhCgP8-RWJMY3RzSVlWRXc

Comment: @yachayx, thanks, I executed the new script. See the edit in my answer above -- I'm still getting a minimum date of `2017-05-12 16:37:17` when I execute your query without the `between` operator. Are you sure the scripts linked in your question include all the data in tables `clientes` and `adicional`? The query yields no data with `clientes.fecha_gestion` between `2017-05-04 00:00:00` and `2017-05-08 23:59:59`. There isn't a matching record in `adicional` for every `id` in `clientes`, and the data in `clientes` that matches your `between` values does not have matching data in `adicional`.